# Graphs of nucleotide percentages, R

Tags: r

I'm trying to graph the nucleotide percentages of 5 different sequences stored in 5 vector each one, I have a function that shows me the percentage of A,C,G,T respectively for the sequences and need to graph the comparison of nucleotides in a single graph, a bar graph was my first idea but don't know how to implement it.

I got the correct answers for each one and had no execution errors, my issue is with the graphs.
I was thinking of ggplot but got stuck with the implementation.

My nucleotide function is this:

```
percentage <- function(sec){
  total_bases <- length(sec)
  A <- sum(sec == "a") / total_bases * 100
  C <- sum(sec == "c") / total_bases * 100
  G <- sum(sec == "g") / total_bases * 100
  T <- sum(sec == "t") / total_bases * 100
  cat("Percentages:\n")
  cat("A: ", A, "%\n")
  cat("C: ", C, "%\n")
  cat("G: ", G, "%\n")
  cat("T: ", T, "%\n")
}
```

Comment: Provide example data input. Maybe a simpler solution: `barplot(table(mtcars$cyl))`.

Comment: Perhaps just: `barplot(100*table(sec)/length(sec))`